# Set an attribute in Guice injected class

Tags: java, junit, dependency-injection, guice

I'm using Google Guice, to bind a class with a mock class for some unit test.
This is my current code:

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(ProductCaller.class).to(MockProductCaller.class);
}
```

In my test:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new JUnitMockBootstrapBinder());


@Before
public void init() {
    injector.getBinding(ProductCaller.class);
    injector.getInstance(ProductCaller.class);
}
```

But in my mock class I have an attribute that I would like to set before the mock is instantiated.

```
public class MockProductCaller extends ProductCaller {
     private String jsonValue; // <---This value
}
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: You can't set anything "before instantiation"; instantiation is the first time the object instance exists for any fields to be set. Can you explain when exactly you need it set, and why you can't set it in the test, or in the mock class's constructor?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject maybe inject a `@Named` property :

```
public class MockProductCaller extends ProductCaller {
     @Named("jsonValue") @Inject
     private String jsonValue; // <---This value
}
```

and then :

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new JUnitMockBootstrapBinder(), 
  new AbstractModule() {
    public void configure() {
      bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("jsonValue"))
        .toInstance("someValue");
    }
});
```